# Does every html page with doctype need internet connection to render page properly?

Tags: html, xhtml, w3c, doctype

many doctype use a url link

like this

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

and this dtd file is on live url http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd

What is the use of this online live dtd and how any page (which use this doctype) will render properly  according to this doctype without having access to this url (i mean if internet access is not available?)

**update :** I found this info from wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_identifier

> In HTML and XML, a system identifier
>   is a fragmentless URI reference. It
>   typically occurs in a Document Type
>   Declaration. In this context, it is
>   intended to identify a document type
>   which is used exclusively in one
>   application, whereas a public
>   identifier is meant to identify a
>   document type that may span more than
>   one application.
>
> In the following example, the system
>   identifier is the text contained
>   within quotes:

**update 2 :** is it only to use for Validators? how some software like dreamweaver provides offline validation?

**update 3:** i found this info from w3c site http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/Doctype

> Why specify a doctype? Because it
>   defines which version of (X)HTML your
>   document is actually using **(version
>   for what browser or validator?)**, and
>   this is a critical piece of
>   information needed by some tools
>   **(which tools? any other tools then validator?)** processing the document.
>
> For example, specifying the doctype of
>   your document allows you to use tools
>   such as the Markup Validator to check
>   the syntax of your (X)HTML. Such tools
>   won't be able to work if they do not
>   know what kind of document you are
>   using.
>
> But the most important thing is that
>   with most families of browsers, a
>   doctype declaration will make a lot of
>   guessing unnecessary, and will thus
>   trigger a "standard" rendering mode.

Comment: I expect that the url is not really used, but it is part of the doctype definition, so it should be there.  But, if there is no internet connection it will work fine anyway.

Comment: Does my answer not already address the questions you added in update 3? Browsers do not care, other than the specific doctypes used for quirks/standards mode switching. Validators usually do care, but usually don't download the DTD. Other tools may or may not care; you'll be able to get a better answer by asking about the tools in question, as there's no one-size-fits-all answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, no browsers actually fetch or validate against the doctype. See [DTDs Don't Work on the Web](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/no-dtd/) for a good argument for why fetching and validating DTDs is a bad idea.

The doctype is there, in theory, to tell what version of the standard the document uses. The browsers generally don't use this information, other than to [switch between quirks and standards mode](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/). All modern browsers accept the simplest possible doctype, with no URL or version information, `<!DOCTYPE html>`, for this purpose; because of this, [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) has adopted this as the recommended doctype.

Validators sometimes use this information to tell what DTD to validate against, but DTDs embedded in the document aren't actually a very good way of specifying validation information. The problem with validating against a DTD referenced within a document is that the consumer of that document doesn't really care all that much whether the document is self-consistent, but whether it follows a schema that the consumer knows how to interpret reliably. Instead, it's generally better to validate against an external schema, in a more powerful schema language like [RELAX NG](http://relaxng.org/).

When validators use this information, they frequently use the URI as an *identifier* only, not as a *locator*. That means that the validator already knows about all of the common HTML doctypes, and uses that knowledge for validation, instead of downloading from the URI referred to. This is in part to avoid the problem of having to download the DTD every time, and also because a DTD doesn't actually specify enough information to provide very good validation and error messages, so some parts of the validator may be specified in custom code or a more powerful schema language. For more information, see [Henri Sivonen's thesis](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/thesis/html5-conformance-checker) on his implementation of the [validator.nu](http://validator.nu/) HTML5 conformance checker.

Some validators may also download and then cache DTDs, so they would need to be online once to download it, but will later work from the cached version.

Comment: but how any browser without internet connection change quirks to strict mode if xhtml file has this system identifier

Comment: Browsers do not actually load the DTD referenced in order to switch between quirks and standards mode; they just do a string match on the `<!DOCTYPE ...>` declaration. No (popular, modern) browser will ever actually load the DTD referenced. Most validators do not either. They just use it as an identifier. Note that many of the doctypes listed in the second link in my answer don't even have a URI, they just use FPIs (formal public identifiers http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_Public_Identifier) like "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN".

Comment: The use of the systemId as a quirks mode signifier is a browser hack that has no relation to the proper purpose of a systemId in locating the DTD external subset. Browsers chose to do this check because people who got the systemId wrong were the people who needed the quirks, but there's nothing magic about systemIds themselves.

Answer (score 2):

The URI is there to identify the document type uniquely - it is not meant for retrieval and no browser (or other piece of software) should rely on a document existing at that web address.

Comment: It's really more of a URI than a URL. Its purpose is to identify the document type - that this also works to actually locate it is incidental.

Comment: It's very much meant for retrieval. An external-entity-including parser such as a validating parser (which a browser isn't) will need the DTD external subset; if it does not have a local copy it will have to dereference the system ID as a URI. You would hope most tools would have a local copy of the well-known HTML DTDs accessible under their public ID though.

Comment: It may be *meant* for retrieval, but that doesn't mean it's a good idea to rely on that. See the RSS 0.91 fiasco for why. If your application will fail to work because the user is offline, the server hosting the DTD is offline, or there is some sort of connectivity problem, then your application is broken. External entities are a bad idea, in SGML, in XML, or in HTML, which is why browsers made the right decision and don't retrieve external DTDs. Again, see http://hsivonen.iki.fi/no-dtd/

Answer (score 0):

I used to wonder about that myself.  But if you have your own HTTP server, it's pretty easy to prove that it doesn't matter.  Just yank the cable to the outside world and see if you can still open the pages on your server.

Comment: Heck, just yank the cable and look at a saved HTML page on your hard disk.

Comment: we don't need any server to prove for just a html file

Comment: Depends on how much you trust the browser to behave the same for local files as it does for files it pulled down from the web.